# Splitting array by id then handling the split arrays

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3, oscommerce

I'm trying to organize a group of arrays that I'm extracting from my database. Here is an example of the array:

```
$productsarray = Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [id] => 789 [pro_name] => Product1 [dsid] => 5 ) 
  [1] => Array ( [id] => 237 [pro_name] => Product2 [dsid] => 3 ) 
  [2] => Array ( [id] => 665 [pro_name] => Product3 [dsid] => 7 ) 
  [3] => Array ( [id] => 164 [pro_name] => Product4 [dsid] => 3 ) 
)
```

I'm trying to group these arrays according to the [dsid] like so:

```
$productsarray[0] = Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [id] => 237 [pro_name] => Product2 [dsid] => 3 ) 
  [1] => Array ( [id] => 164 [pro_name] => Product4 [dsid] => 3 ) 
)

$productsarray[1] = Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [id] => 789 [pro_name] => Product1 [dsid] => 5 ) 
)

$productsarray[2] = Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [id] => 665 [pro_name] => Product3 [dsid] => 7 ) 
)
```

I need them grouped this way so I can run a while loop through $productsarray[] and send off emails to different companies. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are the IDs in the first returned array supposed to be 665?  They are 237 and 164 in the original array

Answer (score 1):

Create a new array using `$dsid` as the first level array key, add all subsequent values to it, then reset the array keys using `array_values`:

```
<?php

$products = array();

foreach($productsarray as $current) {

    $dsid = $current['dsid'];
    $products[$dsid][] = $current; // use $dsid as common array key for now

}

// reset array keys
$productsarray = array_values($products);

?>
```

More info on `array_values`: https://www.php.net/array_values